# Query nested Objects with Case-Insensitive search in MongoDb with Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb-query

My MongoDb contains `Recipes`, which have an array filled with `Ingredients`.
I now want to search for all `Recipes` containing `Ingredients` named *example*.
How ever the query should be case insensitive.

For example:

Return all recipes with the ingredient named *example1*, should return recipes like this:

```
[{
"id":"x",
"name":"recipe1"
"ingredients": ["Example1"]
},
{
"id":"y",
"name":"recipe2"
"ingredients": ["example1","example2"]
}]
```

But return all recipes with the ingredients named *example1* and *example2*, only returns the second recipe:

```
{
"id":"y",
"name":"recipe2"
"ingredients": ["example1","example2"]
}
```

I'm using the Spring MongoRepository Interface to interact with my Db and have annotated my queries with the `@Query` annotation.

Recipe.java:

```
@Document(collection = "recipes")
public class Recipe {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients;

    //Getter, Setter and further fields omitted 
}
```

Ingredient.java:

```
public class Ingredient {

    private String name;
    
    //Getter, Setter and further fields omtted
}
```

RecipeRepository.java:

```
@Repository
public interface RecipeRepository extends MongoRepository<Recipe, String> {

    @Query("{'ingredients.name': {$all: [{$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'}]}}")
    List<Recipe> findByIngredientsNames(List<String> ingredientNames);

    //Further queries omitted
}
```

At first I tried the automatically generated Spring Query without the `@Query`annotation but it failed instantly.

Next I tried the `@Query("{'ingredients.name': {$all: [{$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'}]}}")`, which just returns all recipes, disregarding my arguments.

The Query without the case-insensitive regex works, but I need it to be case insensitive.

So far I tried querying the document on mongodb atlas with the following two queries as a test but i didn't get the results i was hoping for:

```
{
  ingredients: {
    $all: [
      {$elemMatch: {name: {$regex: 'example1', $options: 'i'}}},
      {$elemMatch: {name: {$regex: 'example2', $options: 'i'}}}
    ]
  }
}
```

This query doesn't return anything.

```
  'ingredients.name': {
    $in: [
      /example1/i,
      /example2/i
    ]
  }
}
```

This query returns the recipe I'm looking for but it still returns it when I add an ingredient my recipe doesn't contain.

Comment: I added further information

Comment: ```{$and: [
    { 'ingredients.name': {$regex: 'pasta', $options: 'i'} },
    { 'ingredients.name': {$regex: 'onion', $options: 'i'} }
  ]
}```
works for my intends and purposes but it looks hacky